# How do I update the remote branches list in Git from the server?

Tags: git, repository, branch

How can I update the remote branches list in Git?

I have pushed a branch to Git on the server. On the *second* local copy of the repository, I want to get that branch and do:

> show branch -r

But I don't have the new branch in this list.

How can I update Git's remote branch list?

Comment: just do a `git fetch`

Comment: try `git branch -a` command. If you can't see other branches...did you really push other branches to the server?

Comment: @Wolf after using this command. It still shows deleted remote branches

Comment: `git fetch --prune` will get rid of deleted remote branches and fill in new remote branches at the same time

Answer (score 26):

You can use the following commands to update the list of local branches from remote:

```
git fetch --prune

git pull --prune
```

Also you can set to update the local list of remote git branches automatically every time you run `git pull` or `git fetch` using below command.

```
git config remote.origin.prune true
```

Comment: The prune option works!! if you have named remote branch then we should try like 

```cmd git fetch origin --prune ```

Answer (score 13):

In the second local repository:

```
git fetch        # Retrieves updates from remote repo
git branch -a    # View all local and remote branches
```

Comment: after using these commands. It still shows deleted remote branches

Comment: @MohsinBukhari you can use `git fetch -p` to delete (prune) remote-tracking branches which no longer exist on the remote

Answer (score 12):

Execute the command:

```
git fetch --all
```

So the local repository will download all the new branches/tags that is in the server.

If you want to remove from the local the ones that have been removed from the remote server, try this:

```
git fetch --all --prune
```

As seen in the git doc about the [fetch command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch).

Comment: after using this command. It still shows deleted remote branches

Comment: try `git fetch --all --prune`, will probably clear branches that no longer exist in the remote repository